# how to delete rows in a mysql table having some 1.6 million rows in it

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

While truncating a table in MySQL having 1.6 million rows, It is not showing any response to `truncate` command.

Comment: what do you consider to be "no response"? what are you using to truncate? how long have you waited? please be elaborate with your question

Answer (score 0):

you can use this batch wise repeatedly if you want 'response'. I am using you don't have any index(index would be good on where clause):

```
DELETE FROM `table`
WHERE (whatever criteria if any)
ORDER BY `id`
LIMIT 1000
```

There's another way I read, never tried though:

```
for i in `seq 1 1000`; do 
     mysql  -e "select id from table_name where (condition) order by id desc limit 1000 " | sed 's;/|;;g' | awk '{if(NR>1)print "delete from table_name where id = ",$1,";" }' | mysql; 
 done
```

If you're still looking for faster way, try this approach:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE tbl;

RENAME TABLE tbl TO old_tbl, new_tbl TO tbl;

DROP TABLE old_tbl;
```